# Failed attempt to execute the prepared statement in php CRUD application

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem when it comes to execute the prepared statement that's : `(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)`

I got the code from a php crud tutorial and wanted to add a new field called mosha beside name address and salary. When I added mosha, `(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)` doesn't execute and I get the

> "Something went wrong. Please try again later"

message.

I've checked the code 100 times and I can't find what's wrong

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$name = $address = $mosha = $salary = "";
$name_err = $address_err = $mosha_err = $salary_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    // Validate name
    $input_name = trim($_POST["name"]);
    if(empty($input_name)){
        $name_err = "Please enter a name.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_name, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $name_err = "Please enter a valid name.";
    } else{
        $name = $input_name;
    }

    // Validate address
    $input_address = trim($_POST["address"]);
    if(empty($input_address)){
        $address_err = "Please enter an address.";     
    } else{
        $address = $input_address;
    }


    // Validate mosha

    $input_mosha = trim($_POST["mosha"]);
    if(empty($input_mosha)){
        $mosha_err = "Te lutem fut moshen";     

    } else{
        $mosha = $input_mosha;
    }





    // Validate salary
    $input_salary = trim($_POST["salary"]);
    if(empty($input_salary)){
        $salary_err = "Please enter the salary amount.";     

    } else{
        $salary = $input_salary;
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($name_err) && empty($address_err) && empty($mosha_err) && empty($salary_err)){
        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO employees2 (name, address, mosha, salary) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_name, $param_address, $param_mosha, $param_salary);

            // Set parameters
            $param_name = $name;
            $param_address = $address;
            $param_mosha = $mosha;
            $param_salary = $salary;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

I want to be able to add the "mosha" field beside name address and salary

Comment: In your `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()` you need to add an `s` like so `"ssss"` since there are now four parameters.

Comment: please check in $_POST, what you are getting, if you not getting "mosha" then firstly you need to add into form.